# PHPexcel rangeArray() how to output as table

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am new with `PHPexcel` and learning the library as i go on, i am able to get the data on a specific `sheet` and a specific range. below is my code.

```
require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileType = 'Excel5'; 
$inputFileName = './data/MYexcelData.xls'; 
$sheetname = 'Sheet1'; 

/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/ 
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType); 
/**  Advise the Reader of which WorkSheets we want to load  **/ 
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname); 
/**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/ 
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName); 


$myDataArray = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A2:J30', NULL, True, True);
```

I am able to get the data when i use `print_r`

```
print_r($myDataArray);
```

Now i am stuck on how to output the data properly, i want a table `td` for now to make it look like a cell.

```
 $i = 0 ; 

    foreach($myDataArray as $row){

         echo "<td>".$row[$i]."</td>";  

         $i++;

    }
```

But i get a error. any suggestion would be great! thanks.

`Notice: Undefined offset: 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you’re retrieving a multi-dimensional array of data, as you have multiple columns and multiple cells in your excel cell reference. So you’ll need to use two `foreach` loops, one inside the other.

```
foreach ($myDataArray as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $cell) {
        // use cell data here
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks! no idea its returning a multi-dimensional array.